# Global try catch block

Tags: php

I have main exception class called GlobalException. Then, I have smaller exception classes, for example ArticleException for article database management class. Each of these smaller exception classes handles the exception at local level and then throws GlobalException  , where I can log the error to error log,... Is there some way I could have global try catch block for GlobalException everywhere, where I include some PHP script, without the need to write try catch block for every file?

Comment: That misses the point for try catch blocks, doesn't it?

Comment: From Placeholders_in_use: try `print_r(variable)` to see if the variable is set to what you want it to be.

Answer (score 0):

try `print_r(variable)` to see if the var is set to what you want it to be.

You could also do or die(); to the function.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post - you can always comment on your own posts, and once you have sufficient [reputation](http://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment).

Comment: it looked like there was a var issue, and since I can't comment at the moment :(, I had to do it here.

Comment: I added this as a comment, I understand that not being able to comment is annoying however the entry bar (50 points) is relatively low. If you have some time on your hand, check the new questions for typos/poor formatting and propose an edit; you can also try your hand at the "unanswered" tab. Only 14 points to go, it's one upvote on an answer and 2 approved edits ;)